# Outlook Authorization grant flow

Tags: apex, integration, callout, outlook

I am trying to build an integration with outlook because my requirement needs the calendar to be synced to a custom object. I am able to create a connection in apex using grant flow: *user logs in*->*gets code*->*get token*

The problem is I want to schedule a job to auto sync the calendar every day. How can I get the code without going through the login?

Comment: Request offline scope and store the refresh token and use the refresh flow when the access token expires

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure how to select your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request offline scope and store the refresh token and use the refresh flow when the access token expires